# How to create all day event in Google calendar from Google sheet for other users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, export, google-calendar-api

**Hello Everyone,**

I would like export **events from Google Sheets to Google Calendar**. There is no problem to transfer event to my calendar, but I don't know how to export these events to different user? Yes, I have their calendarID.

Can you help me?

There is my code, which works (for my calendar)

```
function exportToCalendar() {
  var calendarId = "UNIQUE@group.calendar.google.com";
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
  var events = sheet.getRange("A2:C3").getValues();
 
  for (x=0; x<events.length; x++) {
    
    var evt = events[x];
 
    var title = evt[0];
    var date = evt[1];

    calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Do you have edit access on the calendar?

Comment: You need to invite guests. refer `createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate, options)` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate,-options)

Comment: Yes, I have access to the calendar: "can make changes and manage sharing".  But, the error is: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createAllDayEvent')
exportToCalendar @ Kod.gs:18"